# Looping through converted json data in Powershell that don't have key/value pairs, but rather lists of values instead?

Tags: json, powershell, loops

***JSON:***

```
[
  {
    "Category-1": [
      "Value1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category-2": [
      "Value1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category-3": [
      "Value1",
      "Value2"
    ]
  }
]
```

***PowerShell Script:***

```
$jsonToParse = (Get-Content -Path $jsonPath) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($entry in $jsonToParse) {
     log -Message ($entry) #Log function spits output to file
}
```

***Output:***

```
[10:39:03]@{Category-1=System.Object[]}
[10:39:03]@{Category-2=System.Object[]}
[10:39:03]@{Category-3-Med=System.Object[]}
```

How can I parse this?  I have square brackets mixed with curly brackets, and I'm having a hard time finding a foothold with which to really get at the data.

What can I do to get the "Category" names?  What can I do to get the "Values" for each category name?  The fact that these aren't all key/value pairs is what's causing me trouble, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is something like this:

```
# use the -Raw switch to get the file content as one single string
$jsonToParse = Get-Content -Path $jsonPath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($entry in $jsonToParse) {
    # format a string for the log file using the object ($entry) Name followed by the Value
    # This Value can be an array of more than one items, so join these with a comma
    $msg = '{0} = {1}' -f $entry.PSObject.Properties.Name, ($entry.PSObject.Properties.Value -join ', ')
    log -Message $msg  #Log function spits output to file
}
```

output:

```
[10:39:03]Category-1 = Value1
[10:39:03]Category-2 = Value1
[10:39:03]Category-3 = Value1, Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array which contains values ("Category-1" etc). The values contain arrays with values ("Value1" etc).

```
$jsonToParse[0] = Category-1
$jsonToParse[1] = Category-2
$jsonToParse[2] = Category-3

$jsonToParse[1].'Category-2' = Value1
```

If you fill in the above examples, the output is like this!

Comment: Ok.  But let's say I want to loop over all the data in $jsonToParse and extract this information.  How do I do that?  How do I construct a for loop to extract the category names?  How do I then construct a nested for loop to extract each of the values?

Comment: Do something like:
for ($i=0; $i -lt $jsonToParse.count; $i++) {
 $jsonToParse[$i] | Out-String
}

Note that the Out-String is just to show you the output. Inside the loop you can choose to do what you want with the data!